# Get value mentioned in Kth column in Excel in 1 column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have mentioned some columns numbers in certain rows(Col A).
I want to pick value mentioned in that respective column and paste it in 1 same column (Col B)
I unable to tweak it with vlookup to get the result.I believe there must be a better way to do this.Any tips.thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In B3 and copied down to suit please try:

```
=INDEX(D3:H3,A3)
```

[INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd).

Comment: omg! I have never felt so dumb.I thought index was for intersection of both Col and rows.